# How to create and sign EIP1559 Transaction with Go

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, raw-transaction, eip-1559

i am kinda new to golang and i would appreciate any help.

My main purpose is offline signing EIP1559 transactions based on a json using go-ethereum. I have managed to sign legacy transactions following docs and got success on eth transfers but my erc20 transactions were reverted.
I have used `types.NewTransaction()` method and saw that it was deprecated.

I have been digging around the web to find some examples of the new EIP1559 transaction creation using `types.NewTx()` but i have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to create and sign transactions:

```
tx := types.NewTx(&types.DynamicFeeTx{
    ChainID: chainID,
    Nonce: nonce,
    GasFeeCap: feeCap,
    GasTipCap: tip,
    Gas: gas,
    To: &toAddress,
    Value: value,
    Data: txData,
})
```

Comment: Can you please post how you calculated feeCap and gas. This would really help me! Been struggling past two days.

Comment: @Maddy here are some complete examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558034/build-raw-ethereum-transaction-in-go-contract-function-call